# JavaScript If statement checking for object key

Tags: javascript

I’m looking to see if there is a better way to write the following `if` statement?

```
function addGestureendEvent(el) {
  if (el.addEventListener && !el.eventListenerAdded) {
        el.addEventListener('gestureend', doSomething, false);
           el.eventListenerAdded = true;
         }
    };
```

Would I be better explicitly checking for the properly? For example"

```
if (el.addEventListener && el.hasOwnProperty(‘eventListenerAdded’) {
  …
}
```

Thanks for any recommendations.

Comment: They're doing to somewhat different things. What do you need? Do you actually need to avoid inherited properties or not? Do you need to check is value, or its existence?

Comment: @cookiemonster Just its existence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, yes you should use `el.hasOwnProperty("eventListenerAdded")`. That said, I usually don't bother. If you use a reasonably descriptive and most likely unique name as you are here, you should be fine. You can even add your own prefix, like `_dom_eventListenerAdded` so that future developers know to ask you about it if they're confused ;)